# Proof that every closed interval of real numbers is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

I am trying understand a proof that, for real numbers $\alpha<\beta$, the closed interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ is totally bounded. The proof begins by constructing a finite sequence of elements for each $1\leq n$ as follow: for all $0\leq k\leq n$, define

$$c_k:=\alpha+k\cdot\frac{(\beta-\alpha)}{n}.$$

Then the author says "...the open intervals of center $c_k$ and length $2(\beta-\alpha)/n$ form a covering of $[\alpha,\beta]$".

I have shown that, for each $1\leq n$, the finite sequence $(B(c_k,(\beta-\alpha)/n))_{0\leq k\leq n}$ covers $[\alpha,\beta]$. But how does this help me find a covering of $[\alpha,\beta]$ by a finite family of open balls for arbitrary $0<\epsilon$?

For $0<\epsilon$, there obviously exists $1\leq n$ such that $1/n<\epsilon$. But this doesn't imply $(b-a)/n<\epsilon$ which is what I need to show that $(B(c_k,\epsilon))_{0\leq k\leq n}$ covers $[\alpha,\beta]$. Any suggestions?

*Edit:* Am I misunderstanding the intention of the author? Am I using the $c_k$ incorrectly?

Comment: For all $\epsilon$ there is $n$ with $(b-a)/n<\epsilon$.

Comment: "I have shown that, for each.." Good, you solved the problem.